# How to check if a page is translated in Safari browser?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, translation

When a page is translated from one language to another by Safari browser, I want to show a warning message to tell visitor that the page content is not displaying in the original language.

For Google Chrome, we can check the html tag for class="translated-ltr" to determine the above. Any idea how it works for Safari browser?

Comment: you may make your HTML give a warning if it works in Safari in any case, if you did not get the answer to your question. :)